# Date and Time picker in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I like to start a simple work in sinatra(small ruby framework). For this purpose i like to know how to use a date and time picker in ruby. I use a datepicker like below

```
$("#jobdate_from").datepicker(); $("#jobdate_to").datepicker();
```

I wrote this line in an erb file, if anyone know, at least have an idea about this, please share

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your date picker is a HTML/CSS/JS thing.
Write the correct markup in your erb file, put your styleing in a corresponding CSS file and write your initialization in your js file.
To include it in your generated HTML you can set your public folder with the
   `set :public_folder, Proc.new { File.join(root, "static") }`
command. (Has only to be done if it is not called public anyway). Be sure to create a stylesheet/javascript folder underneath.
If you have done this, you can access your js/css files from within your erb file as you would access a normal method because the view is evaluated in the same context as your method where you called it.

Comment: okkkey, danx    but i just need to knew about the date timepicker

Comment: You don't have to do anything in Ruby at all. If you wan't to do it inline in your erb file, than make a script tag with a `$.ready()` function where you write your init ( `$("#jobdate_from").datepicker()` )

Comment: but it just a datepicker, i also need a timepicker with it